# Toggle in Knockout JS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

In my app, I have a list of items. When I click on a particular item, I want some more information to be shown for that particular item with a toggle effect. So far, I have been able to do the toggle, but the issue is that when I toggle I get information for all of the list items rather than just the one I clicked.

```
<div id="order-info-container" class="medium-12 columns" data-bind="foreach: matches, click:$root.test">
   <div class="details" data-bind="visible: $root.expanded">
      <label>Test</label>
   </div>
</div>

self.expanded = ko.observable(false);

self.test = function () {
   self.expanded(!self.expanded());
}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're having one global `expanded` observable instead of extending each item with its own `expanded` flag.

Try to extend each item in your `matches` array with an `_expanded` flag:

```
for (var i in vm.matches)
    vm.matches[i]._expanded = ko.observable(false);
```

The `toggle` method in your view-model:

```
toggle: function(item) {
    item._expanded(!item._expanded());
}
```

And your HTML would be:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: matches">
    <div data-bind="click: $root.toggle, text: title"></div>
    <div data-bind="visible: _expanded(), text: details"></div>
</div>
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uy98r9wa/1/)

Answer (score 2):

This is a **Logical Problem**.

You are repeating a structure for "matches" times. for each item, you are trying to show/hide based on a single root level variable `expanded`. Since you have only one variable to control the visibility of all the elements inside the for loop, it will toggle all the information at once.

You need to have one property per item in the loop to maintain the expand/collapse state or you can change the `expanded` object to `self.expanded = ko.observableArray([]);`

Comment: And what should that ko.observableArray([]); refer to? Any example please?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how your view should look like.

```html
<div data-bind="foreach: matches">
   <div class="details">                              <!-- container -->
      <h1 data-bind="click: toggleExpanded">Test</h1> <!-- sth to click on -->
      <div data-bind="visible: expanded">...</div>    <!-- sth to show/hide -->
   </div>
</div>
```

This view structure dictates a viewmodel structure

```
root
  matches (observable array)
    match (object)
      expanded (observable value)
      toggleExpanded (method)
    match (object)
      expanded (observable value)
      toggleExpanded (method)
    match (object)
      expanded (observable value)
      toggleExpanded (method)
```

But you have

```
root
  expanded (observable value)
  toggleExpanded (method)
  matches (observable array)
    match (object)
    match (object)
    match (object)
```

I'm sure it's clear why this cannot work.